# EF 4.1 Linq to Entities Contains works with List<T> but not T[]

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce, contains

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 on a SQLCE 4 database and my context is a DbContext.

The purpose of the following code is to search for a list of entries where the "ProtocolName" property is contained within a given list.

This version of the code that supplies the list of permitted values as a List works fine:

```
List<string> lstPossibles = new List<string>("Name1", "Name2");
query = from le in context.DaLogEvents where lstPossibles.Contains(le.ProtocolName) select le;
```

However, this version of the code that supplies the permitted values as an array throws an exception when the query.ToList() is invoked:

```
string[] aryPossibles = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2" };
query = from le in context.DaLogEvents where aryPossibles.Contains(le.ProtocolName) select le;
```

The reported exception is:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   Contains[String](System.String[], System.String)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression."

It took me a while to figure out to use List rather than string[] because I've seen a fair number of references on this site to the use of the array method.

Is this an issue with just EF 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Using an array "usually" works as well as using a list or any other `IEnumerable<string>` implementation - *given that* the extension method `Contains` is the standard LINQ extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`.

The exception you get ...

```
...the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.String[], System.String)'...
```

... is surprising because it indicates that the compiler doesn't use the LINQ extension method. If it would use the LINQ method the exception would be something like:

```
...the method 'Boolean Contains[String](IEnumerable`1[String], System.String)'...
```

Or better: If it would use this method there wouldn't be an exception at all.

The question is: Do you have somewhere an extension method `Contains` for `string[]` - either handwritten or perhaps included from some other assembly/namespace? Something like:

```
public static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains<T>(this T[] ary, T value)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If this thing is used (your code would compile) you would indeed get the exception because LINQ to Entities does not know how to translate such a custom method into SQL (="store expression"), no matter how it is implemented.

Comment: Great call!! That was the problem. There was an extension method in a well used and aged "common/utility" class library that has the following signature:

    public static bool Contains<T> (this T[] array, T val)